# Shell Script / Tool to check the MySQL Replication Status?

Tags: mysql, replication

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Monitoring replication on mysql](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/17501/monitoring-replication-on-mysql)

I am running with MySQL Master/Slave Replication on Linux.

Is there any tool/Shell script which monitors the Replication Status and send the email alerts when there is Replication failure.

Comment: I just answered an identical question here http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/17501/monitoring-replication-on-mysql/17558#comment27513_17558

Answer (score 3):

If you don't have a monitoring framework in place, I would highly recommend looking into Nagios. There are others, but for the purpose of this question, Percona has many MySQL [monitoring tools](http://www.percona.com/software/percona-monitoring-plugins/) available. Two of them specifically monitors slave lag and slave failures. From their [blog post](http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2012/02/22/how-to-monitor-mysql-with-perconas-nagios-plugins/):

> The pmp-check-mysql-replication-delay plugin checks for excessive delay, and pmp-check-mysql-replication-running checks that replication is functioning correctly.

Answer (score 3):

[Zenoss](https://community.zenoss.com/home) is another capable monitoring tool.

Writing a simple shell script and setting it up as a cron would also be pretty simple if you only have a couple hosts to monitor.

```
#!/bin/bash

host=my.db.com
user=repl_check
password=xxxx

MSG=`mysql -h $host -u$user -p$password -e 'show slave status\G' | grep Last_SQL_Error | sed -e 's/ *Last_SQL_Error: //'`
if [ -n "$MSG" ]; then
    # email someone 
   echo $MSG | mailx -s "MySQL Replication error" email@yourdomain.com
fi
```